# kohana ORM question

Tags: orm, select, kohana

i am using kohana ORM in order to get some results from the database. My problem is: even though i have consulted the documentation, i can't find a way to select only the column i am interested in. To be more explicit, i have:

```
$sale_stock = Model::factory('product_type')
->where('product_type_id','=', $id )
-> find_all();
```

var dumping it, it selects me all the "SELECT product_type.* from product_type where etc".
But i want to select only the 'stock' field from the salestock table. doing find('stock') instead find_all() returns a weired object... Where am i wrong, and how can i actually select only the column 'stock' using kohana orm?

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ORM methods `find()` and `find_all()` always select all table columns, so there is two ways to get specified fields:

- Load full table rows and get columns
  from it:

> ```
> $sale_stock = Model::factory('product_type')
>    ->where('product_type_id','=', $id )
>    -> find_all();
> // get array of id=>stock values
> $columns = $sale_stock->as_array('id', 'stock');
> ```

- Create special method in model using
  Query Builder:

> ```
> // model Model_Product_Type 
> public function get_stocks($product_type_id) 
> {    
>    return DB::select(array('stock'))
>       ->from($this->_table_name)
>       ->where('product_type_id', '=', $product_type_id)
>       ->execute($this->_db); 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I've pulled the following from the Kohana documentation ...

```
$articles = ORM::factory('article')->select_list('id', 'title');

foreach ($articles as $id => $title)
{
    // Display a list of links
    echo html::anchor('articles/'.$id, $title);
}

// Display a dropdown list
echo form::dropdown('articles', $articles);
```

You could think of it as a discount, two fields for the price of one.

It's common practice for ORMs to return a 'non-standard' object when partial model or merged model fields are requested.  This prevents confusing operations using the original object (ie. how do you save an object when it contains only 2 of 8 fields, plus maybe some fields from another model?).

If you print_r the object, and give me an indication of how that looks ... it might be just what you want.

Comment: for some reasons select_list doesn't work with my query ,it gives me: invalid method error.

Comment: You're right, that's a Kohana 2 method. Fail on my part.  I've looked through the source for the ORM class, there doesn't appear to be anywhere it supports partial selects.  Either using the model directly, sans ORM, or a modification/addition to the ORM functionality would appear to be required.

Comment: yep.. it is weired. i will write a select function in the model (using sql) i guess it is the simplest way. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but i found maybe easier solution:

```
$sale_stock = ORM::factory('product_type')
   ->where( 'product_type_id','=', $id )
   ->find_all();
die($sale_stock->stock);
```